# When to use process.exit in aws lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am using AWS Lambda function in which I make http request calls to fetch files from S3. Sometimes these http requests error out with "Failed to connect to s3".

Full Error :

SEVERE: b.run Inner Exception: Error during S3 call. Unable to execute HTTP request: Operation not permitted (select/poll failed)

One of the recommendation by AWS Support team is to force lambda to use a new container using process.exit when it gets 500 errors.

Is it a common practice to use process.exit() ? What kind of errors should process.exit() be used for?
Should I do a callback before invoking process.exit?

Answer (score 1):

Use your due diligence to find what all error you want to stop lambda function add try catch so will print log error for audit and loging purpose.

```
}).catch((err) => {
   console.log(err);
   callback({ statusCode: 500});
   context.fail()
   process.exit(1); //<--------
   })
```

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html

Comment: context.fail is a deprecated right? Only callback is supported now. Why do we need them both?

Answer (score 0):

`Process.exit()` is never a good way of doing it. This is a hard stop. It will exit with an error - `error : Error: Runtime exited without providing a reason. Runtime.ExitError`

Instead you have to handle the errors in try-catch and decide how the lambda should behave.

Comment: AWS needs to add a clean, reliable way to terminate a running lambda instance.  Until they can do that (and right now they really can't) forcing a running lambda to terminate seems to be the only guaranteed way to force a clean reload.

Comment: If you are in need to using a process.exit /  force clean re-load, I think probably the implementation is not very clean. Please share more context, let me see if I can help with any :)